# Dynamically providing different Services to each instance of Component in Angular?

Tags: angular

Consider I have a dropdown list `@Component` that displays `Entity[]` to choose from.

`@Component` is self-contained and populates dropdown options from `EntityService` by subscribing (reactively) to changes in service, starting in `onInit()` and closing `onDestroy()`.

`Component` has an `@Output() selection: Entity` and `@Input() params: string` used to e.g. filter out data when fetching from `EntityService`.

As my codebase is growing, I noticed that I now require the same dropdown `@Component` (with the same `@Output`, `@Input` and HTML) , but for different `OtherEntityService`.

As it turned out, now I have few of the same components that are different in only injected `EntityService`, `OtherEntityService`, or other - that all (services) extend from the same base interface and accept/return the same type of `@Output`.

I started thinking - it must be possible to pass different service (extending some base interface) to every other `@Component` in different places they are used so that different component instances (but the same class) fetch data from different sources.

**Am I missing something obvious? I guess the question is how to inject or pass different services like you do for simple data with `@Input()`? Or should I start thinking differently.**

EDIT: Note that fetching data in containing parent component and passing it into child via `@Input` is not the way. That's the whole point of making `@Component` self-contained is so that all logic is there, including fetching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to choose a fitting service. In the component (based on some if conditions) or outside.

I would recommend deciding outside of your component which service to use: Therefore you might want to look into the Dependency Injection System that angular provides:

When you have a Class (or an Injection Token)

```
export class BaseEntityService {}
```

you can inject it in your self-contained component

```
class SelfContainedComponent {
    constructor(protected entityService: BaseEntityService) {}
}
```

You are now able to provide different services from the parent classes using that `BaseEntityService`

```
@Component({
    providers: [{ provide: BaseEntityService, useExisting: EntityService }]
})
class Parent1Component {}

@Component({
    providers: [{ provide: BaseEntityService, useExisting: OtherEntityService }]
})
class Parent2Component {}
```

Comment: Okay, so the approach above would be to have a parent Component accepting Service interface and then concrete child Components that extend parent Component with a implementation of Service provided in their decorator. Sounds solid, I will try it. I am still suspecting there is a way to instantiate Components dynamically (with Service of Your choosing) in runtime. I am basing it on https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader . If You can insert Component to DOM in runtime, it must be possible to provide it with different Services during creation, am I wrong?

Comment: I tried to create an example setup for you to better understand the relations between the different classes: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dpjorg 
You only have one child component injecting an abstract service. Which service it will get at runtime will be defined by any parent providing it (see parent1, parent2).

If this solution does not work for you I might not understood your problem correctly...

Comment: Ahh! I get it now. Thanks! I was wrongly thinking I had to use some inheritance between components.